# $p(2p-1)$ is a pseudoprime for half of all bases

Tags: number-theory, legendre-symbol, pseudoprimes

Proposition 4 in [this paper](https://cr.yp.to/bib/1993/jaeschke.pdf). The proof they give is very brief, can someone explain it?

For $p$ a prime, $q=2p-1$, $b$ prime to $N=pq$, why does the following equivalence hold?

$b^{pq-1}\equiv 1 \mod pq \iff b^{p-1}\equiv 1 \mod q$

/edit: I understand now why $b^{pq-1}\equiv 1 \mod pq \iff \left(\frac qb\right)=\left(\frac bq\right)=1$ holds (thanks to N. S.!)

Now I want to show this happens in exactly half of the cases. It is known that $\left(\frac bq\right)=1$ for half of all $b=1,\ldots,q-1$. However, I need to consider $b=q-1,\ldots,N-1$ as well. How?

Answer (score 1):

Since $p,q$ are primes we have by Euler Theorem
$$b^{(p-1)(q-1)} \equiv 1 \pmod{pq}$$

Therefore
$$b^{pq-1} \equiv b^{p+q-2} \pmod{pq}$$

This shows that
$$b^{pq-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{pq} \Leftrightarrow b^{p+q-2} \equiv 1 \pmod{pq}$$

Now, modulo $p$ we have
$$b^{p+q-2} \equiv b^{3p-3} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$$
by Fermat Little Theorem.

Therefore, by the Chinese Remainder Theorem
$$b^{pq-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{pq} \Leftrightarrow b^{p+q-2} \equiv 1 \pmod{q}$$

Now use the fact that $b^{q-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{q}$ and you are done.

**Addedd** For the new question, just use the fact that if $b >q$ then $b=cq+r$ and 
$$b \equiv r \pmod{q}$$

Thus $q+1,..,2q-1$ are simply $1,.., q-1$, $\pmod{q}$ and so on.
Thus the numbers $1,2,..,q-1,q+1,.., N-1$ modulo $q$ are simply the numbers 
$1,2,..,q-1$, each repeated the same number of times.

Comment: Ahh, I get that now. But how can I use this to show it works for exactly half of all bases? See edit above.